# boost filtering streambuf unable to initialise stream

Tags: c++, boost

I am tring to decompress a bz2 file like so:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/bzip2.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
ifstream file (file_name);
boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> in;
in.push(boost::iostreams::bzip2_decompressor());
in.push(file);

std::ifstream input(&in);
```

but execution fails with the messages:

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::ifstream' (aka 'basic_ifstream<char>')
std::ifstream input(&in);
              ^     ~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:131:33: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> *' to 'const std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >' for 1st argument
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY basic_ifstream;
                            ^
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. This is the recommended procedure according to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/iostreams/doc/tutorial/writing_devices.html

Comment: I wanted std::istream, not ifstream...

Comment: If that's the answer (I think so), post it as an answer. Otherwise, just edit the question

Answer (score 0):

I wanted `istream` not `ifstream`.